# Where can I find a reference/tutorial for all vim7.4 bulit-in functions?

Tags: vim

Recently, I found Vim has its own functions.

This trick I learnt online helps me solved a index-number change problem:

```
:s/\d\+/\=submatch(0) + 1/
```

Which I'm sure that `submatch()` is a vim internal function.

I searched online, but I can't find a complete reference/tutorial about all vim's built-in functions so far.

Do you know any good resources about it?

Comment: The built-in functions are documented in vim's own help system : `:h functions`

Comment: Or just run vim. Go to command line with :.. and type in `help submatch`... brought up the help for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find the full list of Vimscript functions at `:help functions`; you can also directly go to the help of a particular function via `:help submatch()`. Many of those have examples (but most aren't applicable / don't make sense in the substitution replacement expression).

Comment: How could I miss that!